# cant draw some arial chars when using canvas fillText method

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to write a simple app that shows all font chars.
I'm using the canvas `fillText` method but not all chars are drawn properly.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta Content-Type:text/html;charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            div  {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"> HELLO !!!!!!!!!! </p>
        <div>
            <p> Before canvas</p>
            <canvas id="cheli" width="1200px" height="1000px" style="border:1px solid #000000;" ></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            var ctx = cheli.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";

            ctx.font = "16px arial";

            ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(172), 1,1);
            charCode = 33;
            numCharsInLine = 20;
            for (var lines = 0; lines < 30; lines++)
            {
                textToWrite = "";
                for (var index = charCode; index < charCode + numCharsInLine; index++)
                {
                    textToWrite += (index + ": " + String.fromCharCode(index) + ", ");
                }
                ctx.fillText(textToWrite, 10, (lines + 1) * 20);
                charCode += numCharsInLine;
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Char number 128-160 are not drawn and I don't know why. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Many of those are control characters or other non-printable characters anyway, I think … http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm

Answer (score 0):

Characters with numbers 128–159 in decimal, 80–9F in hexadecimal, are defined to be control characters (with unspecified effect) in the Unicode standard, which is what both HTML and JavaScript base the character concept on. Character 160 decimal, A0 hexadecimal, is no-break space, which has an empty glyph.

Answer (score 0):

and as promised, this is the unique web chars range coversions we use that works perfectly so far:

```
    var _uniqueWebCharCodesConverter = {
        //see: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html

        128: "\u20AC", //€  Euro Sign
        129: "", // UNASSIGNED
        130: "\u201A", //‚  Single Low-9 Quotation Mark
        131: "\u0192", //ƒ  Latin Small Letter F With Hook
        132: "\u201E", //„  Double Low-9 Quotation Mark
        133: "\u2026", //…  Horizontal Ellipsis
        134: "\u2020", //†  Dagger
        135: "\u2021", //‡  Double Dagger
        136: "\u02C6", //ˆ  Modifier Letter Circumflex Accent
        137: "\u2030", //‰  Per Mille Sign
        138: "\u0160", //Š  Latin Capital Letter S With Caron
        139: "\u2039", //‹  Single Left-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
        140: "\u0152", //Œ  Latin Capital Ligature OE
        141: "", // UNASSIGNED
        142: "\u017D", //Ž  Latin Capital Letter Z With Caron
        143: "", // UNASSIGNED
        144: "", // UNASSIGNED
        145: "\u2018", //‘  Left Single Quotation Mark
        146: "\u2019", //’  Right Single Quotation Mark
        147: "\u201C", //“  Left Double Quotation Mark
        148: "\u201D", //”  Right Double Quotation Mark
        149: "\u2022", //•  Bullet
        150: "\u2013", //–  En Dash
        151: "\u2014", //—  Em Dash
        152: "\u02DC", //˜  Small Tilde
        153: "\u2122", //™  Trade Mark Sign
        154: "\u0161", //š  Latin Small Letter S With Caron
        155: "\u203A", //›  Single Right-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
        156: "\u0153", //œ  Latin Small Ligature OE
        157: "", // UNASSIGNED
        158: "\u017E", //ž  Latin Small Letter Z With Caron
        159: "\u0178" //Ÿ  Latin Capital Letter Y With Diaeresis
    }
```